# visual studio with javascript debugging showing different behaviour while running directly and by running in debug mode

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, ajax

in javascript visual studio database programming, i am fashing very unusual behaviour of program execution.
i have javascript code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetValue6(id1, id2, id3) {
            var user = {};
            user.Username = $("[id*='" + id1 + "']").val();
            user.Password = $("[id*='" + id2 + "']").val();
            alert(user.Username);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<%= ResolveUrl("Default.aspx/SaveUser") %>',
                data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("User has been added successfully.");
                    window.location.reload();
                },
                error: function () { alert("There was an error."); }
            });
            return false;
    }
</script>
```

and code behind file like this:

```
child.Text = "<input type='text' id='" + TextGUID1 + "' value='" + rows[i] 
["Area"].ToString() + "'/> 
<input type='text' id='" + TextGUID2 + "' value='" + rows[i] 
["Area"].ToString() + "'/> 
<input type = 'button' id='" + ButtonGUID3 + "' onclick=\"GetValue6('" + 
TextGUID1 + "','" + TextGUID2 + "','" + ButtonGUID3 + "')\" value='Save' 
/> 

public static void SaveUser(User user)
    {
        string constr = 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users2 
VALUES(@Username, @Password)"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user.Username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", user.Password);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

There is a very strange behaviour that i am facing, when i run above code by clicking "Save" button then i face error alert message "There was an error.". But when i run the program in debugging mode and press F10(Step over new function call) then i get the alert message "User has been added successfully." and user gets insert in the corresponding table. moreover one strange thing is that when e get the error message "There was an error.", even then the corresponding user get inserted into the table successfully.
please guide me where i am wrong and how can i get the username gets inserted with the proper successful message.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the script onclick, also you make and a post back - here, try to return **false** to avoid the post back - write this

```
onclick=\"GetValue6(....); return false;\"
```

or this

```
onclick=\"return GetValue6(....);\"
```

because inside the `GetValue6` you return false.

And when you make debug, the program waits/hold the post back because of the debug step by step - that's why its success.